# Picasso binding adapter 'a connection was leaked' message

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso, android-image, android-databinding

I am using a binding adapter to load images in a recycler view. Images appear fine. While fast scrolling I noticed sometimes I was getting a 'connection leaked' message from Picasso.

The problem comes from dead image links, hardcoding all of my image urls to point nowhere produces the error for every image *after scrolling the first couple off the screen*.

```
W/OkHttpClient: A connection to https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
```

The code is basically identical [to this sample](https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-images-with-data-binding-and-picasso-555dad683fdc).

BindingUtils.kt

```
object BindingUtils {

@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
@JvmStatic
fun setImageUrl(imageView: ImageView, url: String) {
    Picasso.with(imageView.context).load(url).into(imageView)
}
```

xml

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageview_merchant_background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.background}"/>
```

gradle

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.okhttpLoggingVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$rootProject.picassoVersion"

retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
okhttpLoggingVersion = '3.6.0'
picassoVersion = '2.5.2'
```

I can see several references to people needing to closing connections for standard Okhttp requests but seeing as that Picasso load call is a one-liner how can this be leaking?

Comment: Maybe you should cancel previous request, before calling new one: Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(imageView);

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood Picasso is using okhttp3 for handling its network requests. See here the code for Picasso's NetworkRequestHandler class: https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/0728bb1c619746001c60296d975fbc6bd92a05d2/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/NetworkRequestHandler.java

There is a load function that handles an okhttp Request:

```
@Override public Result load(Request request, int networkPolicy) throws IOException {
    okhttp3.Request downloaderRequest = createRequest(request, networkPolicy);
    Response response = downloader.load(downloaderRequest);
    ResponseBody body = response.body();

    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
      body.close();
      throw new ResponseException(response.code(), request.networkPolicy);
    }

    // Cache response is only null when the response comes fully from the network. Both completely
    // cached and conditionally cached responses will have a non-null cache response.
    Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom = response.cacheResponse() == null ? NETWORK : DISK;

    // Sometimes response content length is zero when requests are being replayed. Haven't found
    // root cause to this but retrying the request seems safe to do so.
    if (loadedFrom == DISK && body.contentLength() == 0) {
      body.close();
      throw new ContentLengthException("Received response with 0 content-length header.");
    }
    if (loadedFrom == NETWORK && body.contentLength() > 0) {
      stats.dispatchDownloadFinished(body.contentLength());
    }
    InputStream is = body.byteStream();
    return new Result(is, loadedFrom);
  }
```

I am not too familiar with the Picasso project, but it seems like the response body object is not closed in all cases. You may have spotted a bug in Picasso and may want to file an issue at picasso's github

Comment: Thanks I was thinking it's unlikely little old me had spotted something incorrect going down in Picasso but I have noticed it's not an issue on a Marshmallow emulator (issue was spotted on an Oreo avd),. will do some more digging tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

**Wild guess**, if it has to do anything with the leaking of the **context** of your activity. Try with **applicationContext**

```
Picasso.with(imageView.context.applicationContext).load(url).into(imageView)
```